# Why not to say "a saggy mustache" rather than "a droopy mustache"?

Tags: differences

Why is it rare to find the phrase "a saggy mustache" rather than "a droopy mustache"?
I googled the phrase "a saggy mustache" but it showed very few results, compared to "a droopy/drooping mustache" which is so common that it is included in dictionaries' examples. This is while "droop" and "sag" are synonymous and both mean "to hang down or bend".

Comment: I suggest you post it on ELL or put more information. Or else it will be closed.

Comment: Because "droopy" sounds more mustachey.

Comment: Possibly opinion, but both have negative overtones, but 'saggy' the more so, especially when used of personal attributes.

Comment: You're assuming that the two words are synonyms, but they're not.  Capturing a few common words from brief online dictionary definitions may reveal some similarities, but the only consistent outcome from such "research" is going to be confusion. Follow this [link](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&ei=pAliWpqEHcL8zgLTvbz4CA&q=sag&oq=sag&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i67k1j0l2j0i131k1j0l4j0i131k1j0i46k1j46l2.10227.10818.0.11337.4.4.0.0.0.0.97.227.3.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.3.226.0..0i131i67k1.54.3THktG6B8qA) and read the whole definition...

Comment: Because *saggy* connotes some heaviness, fullness, overripeness. It’s usually reserved for something containing a lot of fluid (that’s not in the definition, but an observed characteristic of the nouns it’s applied to). Mustaches are dry, airy, not heavy, made of a legion of hairs, not a single cohesive mass, and so on.

Comment: It used to be called a 'poncho' moustache, where I come from.

Comment: I would argue that sagging frequently occurs in the middle of something whereas drooping tends to occur at one or both ends. Thus a flower droops when its head dips downward, but a belly sags when it pooches out over a belt or an elastic waistband. There is some overlap, however, as _sag_ may apply to certain instances of _droop_.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Sven Yargs - a sagging moustache could be falling down in the centre (maybe.. It's a fake moustache...?) whereas droopy is hanging down at the sides. Sag implies something that once was straight but now arches downwards - a line that has gone 'off-true'. Saggy moustache would be poetic, it's not really a normal expression, whereas droopy moustache is.

Answer (score 1):

*Droopy* typically implies that the edges hang down while the centre is supported. So imagine pointing your index finger straight up into the sky, and you place a tissue on it, the centre of the tissue will sit on your finger, while the four corners will droop down.

*Saggy* implies the the centre lacks support, while the edges have support. So if you were to hold the four corners of a tissue, the centre would "sag" down due to gravity.

So by looking at the shape of a moustache, which looks like "∩". The edges point down, therefore moustaches are droopy and not saggy.

Comment: @TamO'Shanter if you think we have answered your question, please kindly select the answer you find fit.

Answer (score 0):

I was approaching from the direction of saggy is a state of being, while droopy is more a(n) (inherent) quality.